# How to create function filter reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, filter

In the image below is the review layout, I want to create a filter function. if the customer chooses a one star filter, then the one that will appear in the layout below the filter is only one star and so on, then if the customer chooses With Photos then only displays reviews with photos and vice versa Dengan Deskripsi (With Description)

[image]

below is the source code that displays the image above

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import RatingCardProductDetail from '../../components/RatingCardProductDetail';
import "./style.sass";
import FilterReviewProductDetail from '../../components/FilterReviewProductDetail';
import { Row, Col, Pagination, Spin } from 'antd';
import LatestReview from '../../components/LatestReview';
import strings from '../../localization/localization';
import Product from '../../repository/Product';

function ReviewProductDetail({ productId }) {
    const [reviewRatingDetail, setReviewRatingDetail] = useState({})
    const [reviewRating, setReviewRating] = useState([])
    const [notFound, setNotFound] = useState(false)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [ratingStar, setRatingStar] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        getReviewRatingDetail();
        getReviewRating();
        setRatingStar('')
    }, [productId])


    async function getReviewRatingDetail() {
        let reviewRatingDetail = await Product.reviewRatingDetail({
            productId: productId
        })
        if (reviewRatingDetail.status === 200) {
            setReviewRatingDetail(reviewRatingDetail)
        } else {
            setReviewRatingDetail({})
        }
    }

    async function getReviewRating() {
        let reviewRating = await Product.reviewRating({
            productId: productId,
            loading: setLoading
        })
        if (reviewRating.status === 200) {
            setReviewRating(reviewRating)
            setNotFound(false)
        } else {
            setReviewRating([])
            setNotFound(true)
        }
    }

    function actionChangeSelectFilter(e) {
        console.log(e);
        setRatingStar(e)
    }

    const filterReviewRating = reviewRating.review &&
        reviewRating.review.filter(review => {
            return Object.keys(review).some(key =>
                review[key].toString().includes(ratingStar)
            );
        })

    console.log('filterReviewRating', filterReviewRating);

    return (
        <Spin spinning={loading}>
            <div className="mp-review-product-detail">
                {notFound ?
                    <div className="mp-product-detail__not-found">
                        <span>
                            Belum ada ulasan untuk produk ini
                        </span>
                    </div> :
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <RatingCardProductDetail
                            reviewRatingDetail={reviewRatingDetail} />
                        <Row>
                            <Col md={17} offset={3}>
                                <div className="mp-review-product-detail__filter">
                                    <FilterReviewProductDetail
                                        actionChangeSelectFilter={actionChangeSelectFilter} />
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <h3>{strings.latest_review}</h3>
                        {reviewRating.review &&
                            filterReviewRating.map((review, i) => {
                                return <LatestReview key={i} review={review} />
                            })}
                        <Pagination
                            className="mp-pagination-review-product-detail"
                            defaultCurrent={1}
                            total={5} />
                    </React.Fragment>}
            </div>
        </Spin>
    );
};

export default ReviewProductDetail;
```

and this is the source of the filter button that I marked in red color

```
import React from 'react';
import { Rate, Radio } from 'antd';

function FilterReviewProductDetail({ actionChangeSelectFilter }) {

    const filterReviewMap = [
        {
            name: 'Semua',
            value: ' ',
            icon: ''
        },
        {
            name: 'Dengan Foto',
            value: 'Dengan Foto',
            icon: ''
        },
        {
            name: 'Dengan Deskripsi',
            value: 'Dengan Deskripsi',
            icon: ''
        },
        {
            name: '1',
            value: 1,
            icon: <Rate disabled defaultValue={1} count={1} />
        },
        {
            name: '2',
            value: 2,
            icon: <Rate disabled defaultValue={1} count={1} />
        },
        {
            name: '3',
            value: 3,
            icon: <Rate disabled defaultValue={1} count={1} />
        },
        {
            name: '4',
            value: 4,
            icon: <Rate disabled defaultValue={1} count={1} />
        },
        {
            name: '5',
            value: 5,
            icon: <Rate disabled defaultValue={1} count={1} />
        }
    ]
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <span>Filter</span>
            <Radio.Group
                defaultValue={"Semua"}
                size="large"
                onChange={e => actionChangeSelectFilter(e.target.value)}>
                {filterReviewMap.map((review,i) => {
                    return <Radio.Button key={i} value={review.value}>
                        {review.name}{review.icon}
                    </Radio.Button>
                })}
            </Radio.Group>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default FilterReviewProductDetail;
```

[then I make it directly in Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-dream-yzqsf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make an excellent filter function ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300773/how-to-make-an-excellent-filter-function-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this one](https://codesandbox.io/embed/runtime-dust-5puvq)

You need to fix your filterReviewRating to filter the right amount of stars

Original

```
const filterReviewRating = dataDummy.filter(review => {
    return Object.keys(review).some(key =>
      review[key]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(ratingStar)
);
});
```

New

```
const filterReviewRating = dataDummy.filter(review => {
    //Check if ratingStar is empty
    if (!ratingStar) 
        return true;
    return review.rating == ratingStar;
});
```

And you also nee to change LatestReview/index.js

```
<Rate disabled defaultValue={rating} />
```

to

```
<Rate disabled value={rating} />
```

Comment: this is solved for selecting stars only, but for the function with Photos and with descriptions not working?

Comment: Its pretty much the same, check if the data has images or message with [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) then display it

Comment: I can't think of making it, can you help it

Comment: please heeeelp me

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be use state to store the "star" value. Refer to [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

```
const [starFilter, setStarFilter] = useState('all');
```

Once you have the state updated by the buttons, you can easily apply to each element with something like this.

```
{filterReviewMap.map((review,i) => {
    return (starFilter=== 'all' || starFilter===review.value) &&
        <Radio.Button key={i} value={review.value}>
            {review.name}{review.icon}
        </Radio.Button>
})}
```