# how to make an excellent filter function ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

below this picture the box that I marked in red is a filter whose job is to filter if you choose one star then only one star will appear and so on .. the problem now
I have not gotten a good logic for filters Dengan Foto (with photos),Dengan deskripsi (with description) and Semua (all)

[image]

below is the source code that displays the image above

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./style.sass";
import dummyReview from "./dummy/dummyRivew";
import LatestReview from "./LatestReview";
import { Tabs, Row, Col } from "antd";
import FilterReviewProductDetail from "./FilterReviewProductDetail";

function App() {
  const [ratingStar, setRatingStar] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setRatingStar("");
  }, []);
  const dataDummy = dummyReview.data;

  const filterReviewRating = dataDummy.filter(review => {
    if (!ratingStar) return true;
    return review.rating == ratingStar;
  });

  function actionChangeSelectFilter(e) {
    setRatingStar(e);
  }

  console.log(filterReviewRating);

  return (
    <div className="mp-review-product-detail">
      <Row>
        <Col md={17} offset={3}>
          <div className="mp-review-product-detail__filter">
            <FilterReviewProductDetail
              actionChangeSelectFilter={actionChangeSelectFilter}
            />
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Tabs className="tabs-detail" defaultActiveKey="1" type="card">
        <Tabs.TabPane tab="PERTANYAAN" key="1">
          {filterReviewRating.map((review, i) => {
            return <LatestReview key={i} review={review} />;
          })}
        </Tabs.TabPane>
      </Tabs>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

and this is the source of the filter button that I marked in red color

```
import React from "react";
import { Rate, Radio } from "antd";

function FilterReviewProductDetail({ actionChangeSelectFilter }) {
  const filterMap = [
    {
      name: "Semua",
      value: "Semua",
      icon: ""
    },
    {
      name: "Dengan Foto",
      value: "DenganFoto",
      icon: ""
    },
    {
      name: "Dengan Deskripsi",
      value: "DenganDeskripsi",
      icon: ""
    },
    {
      name: "1",
      value: 1,
      icon: <Rate disabled defaultValue={1} count={1} />
    },
    {
      name: "2",
      value: 2,
      icon: <Rate disabled defaultValue={1} count={1} />
    },
    {
      name: "3",
      value: 3,
      icon: <Rate disabled defaultValue={1} count={1} />
    },
    {
      name: "4",
      value: 4,
      icon: <Rate disabled defaultValue={1} count={1} />
    },
    {
      name: "5",
      value: 5,
      icon: <Rate disabled defaultValue={1} count={1} />
    }
  ];
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <span>Filter</span>
      <Radio.Group
        defaultValue={"Semua"}
        size="large"
        onChange={e => actionChangeSelectFilter(e.target.value)}
      >
        {filterMap.map(button => {
          return (
            <Radio.Button value={button.value}>
              {button.name}
              {button.icon}
            </Radio.Button>
          );
        })}
      </Radio.Group>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default FilterReviewProductDetail;
```

[then I make it directly in Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/runtime-dust-5puvq)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be actually asking a question, and also looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296259/how-to-create-function-filter-reactjs